# Get MailItem Recipient using Redemption.ISafeMailItem object

Tags: outlook, c#-2.0, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I am writing simple Outlook program in C# which records MailItem’s Recipients for sent mail. To build that I am hooking into Outlook Mailitem `Send` event to get `Recipient` collection. Also to avoid Outlook security prompt I am using Redemption `SafeMailItem`.

For reading `Recipient` collection I am assigning `MailItem` to `SafeMailItem` and read `Recipients`. However `Recipient` collection won’t be same if `MailItem` has unsaved changes. In order to copy `Recipient` collection, `MailItem` requires to be saved and then access via Redemption `SafeMailItem`.

#### Here is example.

```cs
//event handler
void _MailItemSend(ref bool Cancel)
{
    SafeMailItem safeMailItem = (SafeMailItem)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(RDOCustomClasses.SafeMailItem));
    SafeRecipients recipients = null;

    safeMailItem.Item = mailItem; // Assigning original mailItem which getting sent by outlook without saving it (just compose & send email before it get autosaved by outlook or manually)
    recipients = safeMailItem.Recipients

    // If mailItem have unsaved changes safeMailItem.Recipients will be different. 
    recipients.Count != mailItem.Recipients.Count;
}
```

So I believe calling `Save()` makes sense but I am not changing anything and calling `Save()` is causing another issue. When I try to quit Outlook it says:

> there are unsaved changes “ do you want to save change”.

I tried accessing directly `Mailitem.Recipients` (*it has latest and unsaved recipient list before mail getting send*) but it creates Outlook security prompt. If I used Redemption it requires call to save before accessing it which creates other issue.

Is there a better way to receive Outlook **Sent Mail Recipients** in safe manner without modification ? Your suggestion will be appreciated.